# How to use nested function or multiple function on onSubmit react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is My Code

```
function MyModal(props) {
    const [modalIsOpen, setmodalIsOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={()=>{setmodalIsOpen(true)}}>Open modal</button>
        <ListItems items={props.items}
    deleteItem={props.deleteItem}
    setUpdate={props.setUpdate}
    />
       <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={()=>setmodalIsOpen(false)}>
       <header>
      <form id="to-do-form" onSubmit={props.addItem}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text"
        value={props.currentItem}
        onChange={props.handleInput}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </header>
  
         <button onClick={()=>{setmodalIsOpen(false)}}>Close</button>
       </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The Problem is i want to close the modal `onSubmit` of form.
But When i use `setmodalIsOpen(false)` on another page(app.js) it is undefined there.
if i declare another function which contains the bothe `props.addItem` and `setmodalIsOpen(false)` there than both things are undefined.

And This is my addItem metho which is on another page

```
addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem=this.state.currentItem;
    console.log(newItem);
    if(newItem!==""){
      const newItems=[...this.state.items,newItem];
      this.setState({
        items:newItems,
        currentItem:{
          text:'',
          key:''
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please read https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing you have to just work on `onSunmit={addItem}`

make a third function and call two functions inside it .

```
    const addItem=(e)=>{
    props.addItem(e)
    setmodalIsOpen(false)
  }
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the parent component state for showing model pass parent state with props and update state on addItem (if your addItem is in your parent component)